# Getting custom .to_s working in arrays

Tags: ruby

I have a custom class with a custom `.to_s` method. Calling `.to_s` on an individual object works fine, but if I call `.to_s` on an array of said objects, I get nothing but hash marks:

```
class Custom
  def to_s
    'custom thing'
  end
end

c1 = Custom.new
c1.to_s # => 'custom thing'
c2 = Custom.new
c3 = Custom.new
[c1,c2,c3].to_s # => [#,#,#]
```

How can I make my custom `.to_s` work with array items?

Comment: It works for me when I say `p [c1, c2, c3].to_s` May be implementation specific.

Comment: `Array#to_s` seems to behave differently across Ruby implementations. With Ruby 1.8 the above code returns `"custom thingcustom thingcustom thing"`, 1.9 returns `"[custom thing, custom thing, custom thing]"`, 2.0 returns `"[#<Custom:0x007fd04d583ef8>, #<Custom:0x007fd04d583ed0>, #<Custom:0x007fd04d583ea8>]"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Override `inspect`

```
class Custom
  def inspect
    'custom thing'
  end
end

c1 = Custom.new
c2 = Custom.new
c3 = Custom.new
[c1,c2,c3].to_s # => "[custom thing, custom thing, custom thing]"
```

Answer (score 1):

This is where you'd use `map`:

```
c1 = Custom.new
c1.to_s # => 'custom thing'

c2 = Custom.new
c3 = Custom.new

[c1,c2,c3].map(&:to_s) # => ['custom thing','custom thing','custom thing']
```

Answer (score 1):

The default `to_s` on Array is now an alias for `inspect` and the same is applied on all contained object, however in Ruby 1.8 it was equivalent to `join(' ')` and called `to_s` on the elements.

In general you shouldn't be using `to_s` on Array or Hash objects, the output is always messy.

```
[ c1, c2, c3 ].join(' ')
# => "custom thing custom thing custom thing"
```

Comment: @tadman- Good to know. And yea know it's messy, just using it for quick and dirty debugging..

Comment: For debugging, make a "pretty" version of `inspect` of any objects you might encounter. I usually write one when there's a lot of messy internals that don't really matter.